# How to define an annotation for more than one target in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, annotations

In Java, to define an annotation for more than one target, the curly braces can be used:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD})
public @interface AnnotExample {
    String name();
}
```

However, this doesn't work in Groovy:

```
$ groovyc AnnotExample.groovy
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
AnnotExample.groovy: 8: expecting '}', found ',' @ line 8, column 26.
   @Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD})
                            ^

1 error
```

How can this be done in Groovy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Groovy, the syntax is the list one – i.e. with square brackets:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target([ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD])
public @interface AnnotExample {
    String name()
}
```